# Linking android XML to a Java class?

Tags: java, android

I have "main_activity.xml" which is linked to MainActivity.java class, but I wish to link my "login_activity.xml" to "Login.java" class.

- How to link each android XML to separate Java class ?

Comment: how to link means you want to use login_activity.xml in Login.java like setContentView , or you want to just link in eclipse xml editor ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
public class Your_Class_Name extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Your_XML_FileName);
        ...
    }
}
```

This is how you do it.

Comment: And there is no need to be described something in the XML ?

Comment: Ofcourse you have to define layout code in the xml. But nothing about the Java File.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already told that,
You want to link your `Java` with `XML` file.

To do it, you don't need to change anything in your `login_activity.xml` file.

This block of code you have to use in your Login.java:

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity.xml);
        ...
    }
}
```

> Remember a *className* always starts with a capital letter. Your
> *filename* must be same as your *className* in your `.java` file.