# android app behaving strangely

Tags: android

I am creating a simple app which will take data from the user to signup and then allow users to login.

The default layout of the app is login where you have an option to signup or login.

If the user already has an username and tries to login, the app works as expected and after verifying opens the welcome page.

However on clicking signup button the singup page is opened, where user can enter details for signup and then click on the signup button.

On success a new user is created and he/she is redirected to the login page.

The trouble arises when I try to login once I have been redirected from the signup page to login page.

I get the following error, and the login page reloads by itself.

```
12-29 17:20:02.327    5823-5823/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: in.techbreeze.android.cake, PID: 5823
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method login(View) in the activity class in.techbreeze.android.cake.Signup for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'login_button'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3815)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4443)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18433)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: login [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3808)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4443)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18433)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As you can see it is searching for the onClick Handler `login` in the `signup.java` file instead of the `login.java` file. Why is this happening?

This is the `login.java` file code

```
    package in.techbreeze.android.cake;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText login_username, login_password;
    String uname, pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        login_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
        login_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);

        final Button switchsignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup_button);
        switchsignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent act2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Signup.class);
                startActivity(act2);
            }
        });

    }

        public void login(View v) {
                try{

                    // CALL post method to make post method call
                    post();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    String error = ex.getMessage();
                }
            }



    //Method to get list value pair and form the query
    private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    //Method to post data to webservice
    public void post() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        try
        {
            // Calling async task to get json
            new DownloadOperation().execute();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Handle popout messages
    public void error(boolean flag, String etext) {
        if (flag == true) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Code to handle failure
            login_username.setText("");
            login_password.setText("");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        }
    }

    //Asynctask
    private class DownloadOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String uname = "";
        String pass = "";
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Get user defined values
            uname = login_username.getText().toString();
            pass = login_password.getText().toString();

            //Initiate ProgressBar
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Please Wait", "Loggin you in ...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String response = "";
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://rgbpallete.in/led/api/login");
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                return response;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonStr) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonStr);
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("tag", "Result:\n" + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String message = jsonObj.getString("message");
                    boolean error = jsonObj.getBoolean("error");

                    error(error,message);

                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
   }
```

This is the `signup.java` file code

```
package in.techbreeze.android.cake;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Signup extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText signup_username, signup_password, signup_cpassword, signup_email, signup_phone;
    String pass, cpass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        signup_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_username);
        signup_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_password);
        signup_cpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_cpassword);
        signup_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
        signup_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_phone);

        final Button switchlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        switchlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent act2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
                startActivity(act2);
            }
        });
    }

    public void signup(View v) {
        try{

            pass = signup_password.getText().toString();
            cpass = signup_cpassword.getText().toString();

            if(pass.equals(cpass))
            {
                // CALL post method to make post method call
                post();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Passwords mismatch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                signup_password.setText("");
                signup_cpassword.setText("");

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            String error = ex.getMessage();
        }
    }

    //Method to get list value pair and form the query
    private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    //Method to post data to webservice
    public void post() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        try
        {
            // Calling async task to get json
            new DownloadOperation().execute();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Handle popout messages
    public void error(boolean flag, String etext) {
        if (flag == true) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Code to handle failure
            signup_username.setText("");
            signup_password.setText("");
            signup_cpassword.setText("");
            signup_email.setText("");
            signup_phone.setText("");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        }
    }

    //Asynctask
    private class DownloadOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String uname, pass, cpass, email, phone;
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Get user defined values
            uname = signup_username.getText().toString();
            pass = signup_password.getText().toString();
            cpass = signup_cpassword.getText().toString();
            email = signup_email.getText().toString();
            phone=signup_phone.getText().toString();


            //Initiate ProgressBar
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Signup.this, "Please Wait", "Signing you up ...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String response = "";
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://rgbpallete.in/led/api/signup");
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                return response;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonStr) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonStr);
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("tag", "Result:\n" + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String message = jsonObj.getString("message");
                    boolean error = jsonObj.getBoolean("error");

                    error(error,message);

                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_signup, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

These is the place you can download the project from `http://www21.zippyshare.com/v/88368638/file.html`

P.S: I had implimented the solutions stated here, nothing worked this is the untouched version.

Comment: Where is your `Signup Actvity` code?

Comment: it is obvious why ... login(View) have to be a method in current activity ... there is no connection between activity_login.xml and java class ...

Comment: @Selvin could you tell me how to solve it in an answer? I am really new to android and this is my first app.

Comment: @MD do you need the whole `signup.java` code?

Comment: @Selvin does `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);` not link the `activity_login.xml` file to the `login.java` file? Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645178/linking-android-xml-to-a-java-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the final solution:

activity_login.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Login">

    <TextView android:text="Login to Control Panel" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login_text"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/login_username"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/login_username"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login_username"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/login_username" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Signup"
        android:id="@+id/signup_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login_username"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_above="@+id/login_password"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login_password"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/login_password"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/signup_button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/signup_button" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/login_password"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Login.java

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText login_username, login_password;
    String uname, pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        login_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
        login_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);

        final Button switchsignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup_button);
        switchsignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent act2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Signup.class);
                startActivity(act2);
            }
        });

        /*
            - TIP -

            Try always to do as the following instead of call a method into the xml; because you have
            more control of which xml is being called right here
        */
        final Button btLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        btLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent act2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Signup.class);
                startActivity(act2);
            }
        });   


    }

    //Method to get list value pair and form the query
    private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    //Method to post data to webservice
    public void post() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        try
        {
            // Calling async task to get json
            new DownloadOperation().execute();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Handle popout messages
    public void error(boolean flag, String etext) {
        if (flag == true) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Code to handle failure
            login_username.setText("");
            login_password.setText("");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        }
    }

    //Asynctask
    private class DownloadOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String uname = "";
        String pass = "";
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Get user defined values
            uname = login_username.getText().toString();
            pass = login_password.getText().toString();

            //Initiate ProgressBar
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Please Wait", "Loggin you in ...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String response = "";
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://rgbpallete.in/led/api/login");
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                return response;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonStr) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonStr);
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("tag", "Result:\n" + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String message = jsonObj.getString("message");
                    boolean error = jsonObj.getBoolean("error");

                    error(error,message);

                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

activity_signup.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="in.techbreeze.android.cake.Signup">

    <TextView android:text="Enter details to signup" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/signup_text" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="71dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="71dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="71dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/signup_username"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signup_text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/signup_password"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/signup_password" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/signup_password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signup_username"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Password" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/signup_cpassword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signup_password"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Confirm Password" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/signup_email"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signup_cpassword"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Email" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/signup_phone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signup_email"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Phone Number" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Singup"
        android:id="@+id/signup_button"
        android:layout_above="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/back_button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Signup.java

```
public class Signup extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText signup_username, signup_password, signup_cpassword, signup_email, signup_phone;
String pass, cpass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    signup_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_username);
    signup_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_password);
    signup_cpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_cpassword);
    signup_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
    signup_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_phone);

    /*
        - TIP -

        finish(); instead of Intent act2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(act2);

        When you call startActivity you call another activity and don't back to the last activity. For this, you
        have to use finish() instead.

    */
    final Button switchlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
    switchlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    /*
        - TIP -

        It's like the Login.java TIP

        Try always to do as the following instead of call a method into the xml; because you have
        more control of which xml is being called right here
    */
    final Button btSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup_button);
    btSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try{

                pass = signup_password.getText().toString();
                cpass = signup_cpassword.getText().toString();

                if(pass.equals(cpass))
                {
                    // CALL post method to make post method call
                    post();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Passwords mismatch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    signup_password.setText("");
                    signup_cpassword.setText("");

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                String error = ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
    });
}

//Method to get list value pair and form the query
private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}

//Method to post data to webservice
public void post() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    try
    {
        // Calling async task to get json
        new DownloadOperation().execute();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Handle popout messages
public void error(boolean flag, String etext) {
    if (flag == true) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Code to handle failure
        signup_username.setText("");
        signup_password.setText("");
        signup_cpassword.setText("");
        signup_email.setText("");
        signup_phone.setText("");

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        /*
            - TIP -

            finish() instead of setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

            You have to finalize the activity instead of set another content or call startActivity to back.

            You cannot do like you did here(setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)); because doing it you just change the xml and
            not change the activity, so causing the error that you posted
        */
        finish();

    }
}

//Asynctask
private class DownloadOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String uname, pass, cpass, email, phone;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Get user defined values
        uname = signup_username.getText().toString();
        pass = signup_password.getText().toString();
        cpass = signup_cpassword.getText().toString();
        email = signup_email.getText().toString();
        phone=signup_phone.getText().toString();


        //Initiate ProgressBar
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Signup.this, "Please Wait", "Signing you up ...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String response = "";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://rgbpallete.in/led/api/signup");
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonStr) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonStr);
        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.d("tag", "Result:\n" + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String message = jsonObj.getString("message");
                boolean error = jsonObj.getBoolean("error");

                error(error,message);

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_signup, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

There are some tips that I added into your code; you can find them searching by TIP

Comment: tried it your way but now nothing happens when I click on the login button after the signup page redirects to login

Comment: Do you finalize the Singup.class? Where is the Post() method?

Comment: do you want me to post the complete signup.java code?

Comment: Yes, please post the complete Login.java too

Comment: added the codes as well as the link to download the whole project from. I had made the changes you told nothing happened so I posted the untouched version

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look

Comment: I edited the answer. I hope you like and it helps you

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost its criminal to bind your functions in xml.

Secondly the view(that contains the login button i.e activity_login.xml) seems to be looking for the login function in Signup class. So that leaves you with the option of  removing the `:onClick` from the xml function and binding it in the respective class... i.e Login
and you should e good to go.

Comment: tried it but this time around clicking the login button after a redirect from signup page does nothing